# Toggle Class/Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So for my Website, I want a completion like system where you can show you finished a video or comic. I realised I should have a `div` that starts red but you can click on the `div` to turn green but you can also click again to switch back to red just incase. I did some research and got some answers like `toggleClass`,`addClass` and `removeClass` but the Javascript didn't work for some reason.

Basic Example:

```css
.undone /*Default Class*/
{width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;}

.done /*Replacement Class*/
{width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;}
```

```html
<div class="undone"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the `click` event and toggle inside the handler your `.done` class

**jQuery**

```js
$('#myDiv').on('click', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('done');
});
```

```css
.undone
{width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;}

.done
{width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" class="undone"></div>
```

**Pure Javascript**

```js
const div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

div.addEventListener('click', function() {
   div.classList.toggle('done');
});
```

```css
.undone
{width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;}

.done
{width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="undone"></div>
```